# If $X\sim U(2,10)$, $Y\sim U(10,20)$, and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, find $\mathbb E[X^2Y+3]$.

Tags: probability, expectation

I know that since $X$ and $Y$ are independent that $E[X^2Y+3] = E[X^2]E[Y]+3$

$$2<X,10 \text{ and } 10<Y<20,$$

So I would set up the Integral

$$\int_2^{10} \int_{10}^{20} x^2 y+3[f(x,y)] \, dy \, dx$$

but I am lost on how to find the pdf to multiply the Expected value by. 
Thank you

Comment: You will need $E(X^2)$, which is $\int_2^{10}\frac{x^2}{8}\,dx$.

Comment: There is a crucial difference between $\displaystyle \int_2^{10} \left( \int_{10}^{20} x^2 y+3[f(x,y)] \, dy\right) \, dx$ and $\displaystyle \int_2^{10} \left( \int_{10}^{20} x^2 y+3[f(x,y)] \, dx\right) \, dy$.  You can't just write $\displaystyle \int_2^{10} \int_{10}^{20} x^2 y+3[f(x,y)]$ and be understood.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If you really want to use a double integral, the joint density $f(x,y)$ is $\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{10}$ on the rectangle, and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: Thank You, I understand now, I am simply following direction in my book, would there be a simpler way of working this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have
$$\mathbb E[X^2Y+3] = \mathbb E[X^2]\mathbb E[Y] + 3. $$
We may compute this by
\begin{align}
&\left(\int_2^{10} \frac1{10-2} x^2 \ \mathsf dx\right)\left(\frac{10+20}2\right) + 3\\
&= \left[\frac1{24} x^3\right]_2^{10}\cdot15 + 3\\
&= 63.
\end{align}